# change font in result that shows to user

Tags: html, fonts, resultset

I write a code to calculate sth. I want to change the font and size of words in below code

```
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML =" مقدار رنگ موردنیاز برابر با"+ Math.round(result)+"لیتر";
```

How can I do it? Can I put a border around it too?

Comment: Note that if you're just setting text, don't use `.innerHTML = ...` but use `.textContent = ...` instead. You should almost never need to use `innerHTML` (because for adding real DOM content, we can already build real DOM nodes and add them using `append()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("total").style.fontSize = "x-large";
document.getElementById("total").style.fontFamily = "Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works really well. Can I put a border around it too?

Comment: If it works for please accept the answer.  If you want to add a border you can do that directly with css,

Comment: But try to _not_ to set `style`: instead, have a class in your CSS that contains these rules, and add that class using `element.classList,add("...")`